# registery search of bootstrapper manifest generator

Tags: c#, manifest, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

Registery search of Bootstrapper Manifest Generator allows you to get Registery value of any key.

But what does it return if that key does not exist?

As i want prerequisite to be installed based on if perticular registery key exist or not.

if exist,then not to install prerequisite otherwise install.

How to do this..?

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily achieved by using **ValueExists** comparison in **BypassIf** element:

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="AAA">
   <InstallChecks>
      <RegistryCheck Property="IsInstalled" Key="HKCU\Software\ABC Software\ABC" Value="Installed" />
   </InstallChecks>

   <Commands Reboot="Defer">
      <Command PackageFile="setup.exe" EstimatedInstallSeconds="15" >
         <InstallConditions>
            <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueExists" />
         </InstallConditions>
      </Command>
   </Commands>

   ...

</Product>
```